# asp.net core webapp - OAUTH2 AUTHORIZATION - 401 Error

Tags: bentley-itwin

i want to use the itwin api and i created a little asp.net core 3.1 webapp.
The Authorization endpoint: https://ims.bentley.com/connect/authorize works fine and i get a code.
Now i want to use the code to get the access token with this backend method:

```
string url = "https://ims.bentley.com/connect/token";


        string clientID = "webapp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string secretID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        //string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientID + ":" + secretID));
        //string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(clientID + ":" + secretID));
        string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientID + ":" + secretID));

        var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code));
        nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:44343/signin-callback"));

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", svcCredentials);
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc)).Result;
            var token = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }`
```

Everthing works fine but i get an 401 Error. Use i the wrong BASE64 encoding?

thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the following:

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", svcCredentials);
```

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_Headers_AuthenticationHeaderValue__ctor_System_String_System_String_) for AuthenticationHeaderValue the first parameter is the scheme and we use Bearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to url-encode `client_id` and `client_secret` before using them for Basic authentication, as described in [documentation](https://developer.bentley.com/apis/overview/authorization/#authorizationcodeflow)

> The client must authenticate using the HTTP Basic method and provide the url-encoded clientId and the clientSecret

This is also stated in [OAuth specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)

> The client identifier is encoded using the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding algorithm per
> Appendix B, and the encoded value is used as the username; the client
> password is encoded using the same algorithm and used as the
> password.